# Redirection and the googlebot : a newbie question

Tags: google, redirects

Ok suppose I have some content

> My site !! Usefull Info here about grazillas!

in a htm-file, that can be reached with a url that can change at any time, like

**url1 :** 

`http://www.mysite.com/notfixed.htm?($!abcd)/bs/@id=12`

but I have a fixed url that always will be pointing to url1, even if it changes  like

**url 2 :**

`http://www.mysite.com/redirection.htm?pageId=12`

so when I google on 'grazillas' I would like to get

---

G O O G L E

- http://www.mysite.com/redirection.htm?pageId=12

  - --> Site with usefulll info about grazilla's

---

and NOT :

---

G O O G L E

- http://www.mysite.com/notfixed.htm?($!abcd)/bs/@id=12

  - --> Site with usefulll info about grazilla's

---

Is this the way google behaves, or is there any way to achieve this? 
Is this boiling down to indexing permalinks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of a few ways you can achieve this.

**1. 301 Redirect**

You set up *url1* to do a [301 redirect](http://www.squidoo.com/301) to *url2*. This would mean that Google goes to *url1* and is redirected to *url2* and would therefore index *url2*.

**2. Robots.txt**

You can use [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) to blog Google from indexing the notfixed.htm page. Something like this would work:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /notfixed.htm
```

**3. Canonical**

With Google you can use a special field in the document called [canonical](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) which basically tells google that the link it is checking has another version at this page and that Google should favour that page instead of the one it is currently on. You would do this by putting the following on the page *url1*

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.mysite.com/redirection.htm?pageId=12" />
```

For more information on this topic, [see this page](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66359).